# Unable to access the delete endpoint in asp.net core webapi

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have .net core web api and able to access the get endpoint but not the delete. How do i access the delete endpoint. I am not sure what the problem is ?

I have tried the following

http://localhost:53538/api/cities/delete-city/1

I have been using for the get endpoint.

http://localhost:53538/api/cities

controller

```
 public class CitiesController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ICityInfoService _cityInfoService;

        public CitiesController(ICityInfoService cityInfoService)
        {
            _cityInfoService = cityInfoService;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetCities()
        {
            var cities = _cityInfoService.GetCities();

            if (!cities.Any())
                return NoContent();

            var citiesMapped = cities.Select(MapCity);

            return Ok(citiesMapped);
        }

        [HttpGet("{cityId:int}")]
        public IActionResult GetCity(int cityId)
        {
            try
            {
                var city = _cityInfoService.GetCity(cityId);
                var cityMapped = MapCity(city);

                return Ok(cityMapped);
            }
            catch (CityNotFoundException e)
            {
                return BadRequest(e.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, ex.Message);
            }
        }

        [HttpDelete("delete-city/{cityId:int}")]
        public IActionResult DeleteCity(int cityId)
        {
            try
            {
                _cityInfoService.DeleteCity(cityId);

                return Ok();
            }
            catch (CityNotFoundException e)
            {
                return BadRequest(e.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private static CityDto MapCity(City city)
        {
            return new CityDto
            {
                Id = city.Id,
                Description = city.Description,
                Name = city.Name
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your routing configuration and if you are using IIS on localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your delete method is a HttpDelete, so it needs DELETE request. If you a trying to hit the endpoint via a browser, it won't work as it will just do a GET.

You can use Curl or Postman to issue the DELETE request to your URL.

[image]

Comment: I tried to access the url http://localhost:53538/api/cities/delete-city/1 via postman and it doesnt work

Comment: I just updated my answer with a photo of the DELETE request in postman, did you use that?